# Displaying TVHeadend stream in a browser

Tags: authentication, stream

I am trying to display a TVHeadend stream in the browser as a pre-cursor to get this running on my TV. So I whipped up this sample HTML code where 192.168.0.4 is my server running TVHeadend and the channel UUID is 3df2b09783d8afeb8a323f5025431df7:

```
<html>
<body>
<video width="720" height="567" autoplay="true" controls>
<source src="http://192.168.0.4:9981/stream/channel/3df2b09783d8afeb8a323f5025431df7?profile=webtv-h264-aac-matroska" type="video/webm">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Whether I show the HTML page locally on my computer or served via a local Apache webserver, the result is always the same: I get an emtpy video player control. The network tab does not show any errors, neither does the console. It does bring a warning however:
"Empty src!"

However the src is clearly not empty.
When I copy the src URL to my browser (Chrome) and call it, it starts downloading the stream (instead of showing it, but that might be expected). Why does the video control not seem to be able to show the video?

Do I have any other debug options I can check out? This problem has bugged me for a while now and I have tried to drill down to the source of it by removing the TV SDK and all other side code just to see if the actual video will play (which it does not).

At first I thought it might've been an authorization issue but then why does Chrome seem to be able to download the stream just fine? I have logged on to TVHeadend in the same browser (in a different tab) to make sure that a missing logon is not in the way of things.
I have also tried putting : in between the "http://" and the IP address to pass the parameters required for basic auth - but to no avail.

Does somebody have any hints as to what might be the roadblock here?

Answer (score 0):

I sure that you will have to have some kind of authorization in the url - such as:

http://USER:PASSWORD@192.168.0.4:9981